# Select animation tool at runtime

Tags: canvas, flash

Lets face it: Adobe Flash is still the best animation tool for web and .swf still works smoother than HTML canvas, SVG animation, or GIF (and takes less CPU power too).

But since it doesn't work on iOS and newer Android browsers by default, HTML canvas would be a good alternative.

So, please, how can I achieve a functionality like this

```
if(flashplayer_available) {
  // use flashplayer 
} else {
  // use HTML Canvas
}
```

Comment: Pure HTML or what language you are coding in your website?

Comment: What about [swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion()](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion(versionStr)) ?